# pyHook for 2.7.11 not importing

Tags: python, pyhook

I have a x64 bit operating system and have Python 2.7.11 installed on my alienware 17 laptop but whenever I try and import the whl file into Python C:\Python27\lib\site-packages using pip or any other methods I just does not work. The feedback I get is that some syntax is wrong with line 1. Not sure what that means but I know thats what the problem is. The source I am downloading it from is: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook and it is the pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl file. Im not sure if this is the correct file to install and that is the root problem but if anyone knows what there doing and cares to answer my question please either email me or respond to this post ASAP thankyou.

-Sincerely,
           Matthew/PythonMan

Answer (score 1):

When I installed PyHook, I got it from http://pyhook.sourceforge.net/doc_1.5.0/pyhook-module.html

More specifically, I used HookManager, which is a module in the PyHook package, and it's downloadable from here: http://pyhook.sourceforge.net/doc_1.5.0/pyhook.HookManager-module.html

I have a laptop running windows 10, and I never needed to import it into site-packages or anything like that. It just worked for me after installing.

I hope these packages work better for you than the other site!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it...

1. Download the py hook module that matches your version of python from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook). **Make sure that if you have python 32 bit you download the 32 bit module (even if you have windows 64x) and vice versa.**
2. Open your command prompt and navigate to the folder where you downloaded the module
3. Type "pip install " and then the name of the file.

   Ex: "pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-none-win32.whl"